# Is it safe to assume that a nonce may be validated more than once?

Tags: ajax, security, nonce

From what I have gathered, once a nonce is generated it is valid for reuse for the next 48 hours.

Is it safe to code with this in mind? I'm writing a plugin that does a bit of toing and froing with the client via AJAX and want to know if I should just generate a nonce when the page loads and use that for all communication or generate a new one for every request and include it in the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1, the nonce lifetime is about 24 hours by default actually. take a look at [wp_verify_nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce#Return_Values) function.

To be more accurate, the lifetime is controlled by filter

```
apply_filters( 'nonce_life', DAY_IN_SECONDS );
```

2, if the lifetime value makes you doubt if it is "an implementation side-effect", you may want to `add_filter('nonce_life',create_function('$v', 'return 60*5;'));` to shorten the lifetime to 5 minutes in my example.

3, if you're concerned about the security of your plugin, you should use [csrf token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691492/csrf-tokens-vs-nonce-confusion-are-they-the-same) instead.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress nonces are not use-once. You can reuse the nonce as often as you like until it expires.

Comment: I was more asking if this was a conscious and deliberate design decision or just an implementation side-effect that may be unexpectedly fixed at some point in the future.